# Error TS2440 (TS) Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'PluginConfig'

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I am trying to run my application in Visual studio 2017 and I keep getting the error:

```
 "Error TS2440  (TS) Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'PluginConfig'"
```

I tried downgrading my typescript, but the error is not going away. Below is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular5-time-picker": "^1.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^2.9.6",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Below is the screen shot of angular/cli version:

[image]

I tried opening the application in both Visual studio 2017 and 2019 and I getting the same error in both versions of Visual studio. I also tried to change the typescript version in Visual studio itself, but that didnt work either. Below is the screen shot from Visual studio Typescript version:

[image]

any help in resolving this error will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue with the latest version[s] of Typescript greater than 3.6.4. As far as I can tell, there has been no fix for it in 3.7 or 3.8 which is the version I am on.

you can add the following to your tsconfig.json at your root folder to silence the error:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   ...,
   "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

This solution was offered in this thread:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5348

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this with VSCode and Angular 9. Seems the issue was with VSCode's auto-import of EventEmitter from Protractor rather than @angular/core.  Was wondering why VSCode was complaining that EventEmitter didn't have the subscribe() method available.

`import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';`

should be
`import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

Changed the import and all is well.

Comment: I see the accepted answer has changed to this answer, but I'm not sure how this can be. This appears to be unrelated to the original issue.

Comment: I would tend to agree. My comment was only focused on the symptom and not the specific question.